# Using a name instead of numbers in theorems

Tags: formatting, ntheorem

I would like to have theorems with ntheorem which have no number, but instead of the number a name is used. The referencing to such theorems is already discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767389/referencing-a-theorem-like-environment-by-its-name

But I still have a formatting issue. (I am actually not sure what the ideal formatting would be, maybe you can help me with this, too?) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools}

%https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767389/referencing-a-theorem-like-environment-by-its-name
\makeatletter
\def\namedlabel#1#2{\begingroup
   \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
   \label{#1}\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{goal}{Goal}

\begin{document}

\begin{restatable}{goal}{goalName}{\textbf{Name}}
\namedlabel{thm:name}{Name}
Goal without number, but with name.
\end{restatable}

We refer to the Goal~\ref{thm:name}:

\goalName*
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

And somehow the theoremseparator seems to be wrong the way it is? And is textbf+italics a good decision for the name?

Thank you, all the best,
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the way to use the optional argument in the `restatable` environment: it has to be given as the first argument,between brackets. I took the opportunity to redefine the `nonumberplain` theorem style, so as to automatically  incorporate the optional argument in the label.

I wasn't sure whether you want the parentheses for the optional argument or not, so I didn't change this feature, but they're easy to remove from the redefinition of the style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}

%https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767389/referencing-a-theorem-like-environment-by-its-name
\makeatletter
\def\namedlabel#1#2{\begingroup
   \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
   \label{#1}\endgroup}
\renewtheoremstyle{nonumberplain}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip\labelsep ##1\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont\hskip \labelsep ##1\ (##3)\theorem@separator\namedlabel{thm:name}{##3}]}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{goal}{Goal}

\begin{document}

\begin{restatable}[Name]{goal}{goalName}%
Goal without number, but with name.
\end{restatable}

We refer to the Goals~\ref{thm:name} :

\goalName*

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Oooh I see, so the {\textbf{Name}} was simply rendered as text, and was not even interpreted as argument? Works fine with correct use of parameters.